# wordpress orderby=rand not working

Tags: wordpress

```
$hpPromo = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'homepage_promo', 'orderby' => 'rand'));
print_r($hpPromo->posts);
```

Every time the `array` is the exact same order. Why aren't my posts randomizing? Is it because I'm using a *custom* `post_type`? Please advise.

** EDIT **

In the meantime I'm doing this the only way I know how (inefficient). By all means please post an answer better than this one (for the sake of developers everywhere!)

```
$hpPromo = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'homepage_promo', 'orderby' => 'rand'));
$count = count($hpPromo->posts);
$posts = (array)$hpPromo->posts;
$promo_id = $posts[rand(0, $count-1)]->ID;
wp_reset_query();
$hpPromo = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'homepage_promo', 'p' => $promo_id));
$hpPromo->the_post();
the_content();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try removing filters which might be interfering with orderby query.

```
remove_all_filters('posts_orderby');
$hpPromo = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'homepage_promo', 'orderby' => 'rand'));
print_r($hpPromo->posts);
```

Comment: Thank you Jack. Plugin you have been using might have added hook on this filter. Glad that it worked.

Comment: remove_all_filters('posts_orderby'); definitely helped on my query, thanks