# How to display 5 random posts in WordPress? My Loop isn't working?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The loop was working fine until I added the query to further customize my loop. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried adding wp_reset_postdata(); before the closing end while & end if to no avail. Unless there's another issue that I'm not seeing?

```
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'orderby'        => 'rand',
        'posts_per_page' => '5',
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            $my_query->the_post();

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/entry_cards', get_post_type() );

        } // end while
    } // end if

    ?>
```

I would like to be able to see 5 of my WordPress posts in a random order (as stated in my array).

Comment: Take a look at this post [wordpress orderby=rand not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763290/wordpress-orderby-rand-not-working#11763722)

Comment: Just tried this but unfortunately, it doesn't work...Also, my posts aren't showing *at all* using the code in my original question.

Comment: I think your `$args` array, needs `'post_type' => 'post'`

Answer (score 0):

**I believe this:**

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => '5',
);
```

**Should be:**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => '5',
);
```

`WP_Query()` needs to know what kind of data to pull.